# function isn't working as expected

Tags: php, arrays, function, math

I am working on a function that accepts 2 parameters, `$base` and `$top`

I am looking to return the power of the `$base` which would be less than `$top`
and
the exponent.

The outputs that i am expecting is `$power=125` and `$exp=3`.

I've managed to get `$exp` correct, but my `$power` is coming up as 625 and I cannot figure out why it is going over `$top`.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$base = 5;
$top  = 130;

function topPower($base, $top) {

    $exp = 0;
    while($power<$top) {
        $exp++;
        $power = pow($base, $exp);  
    } 

    return array($power, $exp-1);
}

$results = topPower($base, $top);
print_r ($results);
?>
```

Comment: is it math assignment?

Comment: why have you initialized `base` and `top` as strings ?

Comment: where is `$power` defined ?

Comment: its a practice for coding functions, but this one has math calculations and im not sure how it supposed to work exactly. Not an assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `return array($power, $exp-1);` to `return array( pow($base, $exp-1), $exp-1);`

You are returning the value for `$power` based on `$exp`, not `$exp-1`.

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving this value because 125 is lower than 130 so it executes one more time ;) You should always check the next one and if it exceeds - return the previous power.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that 5 to the power of 3 is 125 and that is just under "$top" which is 130. So your while loop continues to do another calculation which is 5 to the power of 4, to which the answer is 625.

try

```
<?php
$base =5;
$top  =130;

function topPower($base, $top) {

$exp = 0;
while($power<$top) {
$exp++;
$power = pow($base, $exp);  
} 

return array(pow($base, $exp-1), $exp-1);
}

$results = topPower($base, $top);
print_r ($results);
?>
```